# PFUser.currentUser() never equals nil

Tags: ios, swift, pfuser

I'm getting a strange behavior with Swift and Xcode 7. This didn't happen on Xcode 6. I have disabled Anonymous users on Parse. I have logged out the current user. Every time I come back to the login screen...whether I logout the user in the background or even if i logout and then restart the app the PFUser.currentUser() never equals nil. It always allows the user to get to the main screen. I have even tried to logout the user right before the following statement is execute, but PFUser.currentUser() still not nil!

Anyone having the same problem? This started happing after the update.

```
if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
                // Do stuff with the user
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "main", bundle: nil)
                let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainVC")
                self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out:

```
var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()?.username

if currentUser != nil {
    // Do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: #Money! Thanks man that did the trick. Simply change var to let. This worked for me.  PFUser.currentUser() is not nil, but when at this point the username is nil, since it hasn't been saved.

Comment: Cool, glad it helped. Could you please accept the answer so others could also get benefitted. Cheers :)!

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the objectId of the user instead of the username because the username could be changed but objectId can never change.

```
    let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId
if currentUser != "" {

}
```